# Can I make fgets() accept only letters?

Tags: c, string, validation, fgets

so in this database I need to have certain limitations like the Name only letters and so.

but if I use the scanf("%s, c.name) for e.g., it only reads up until to the first space so if 
I had to add 2 names like Marie Claire, I cannot use scanf.

I have a method which checks whether the string contains a digit or not (will provide it) but I was wondering if I could make the fgets() accept only the letters. I'll provide what I tried as well, but when I used this method, it's not accepting any input just skips it.

```
printf ("\nPlease enter Name:\n");
    while (fgets (c.name, sizeof (c.name), stdin)  && cCheck(c.name,100) == FALSE);
    {

    }
```

the method to check for digits [boolean is made with typedef from my side]

```
boolean cCheck(char *test, int max)
{
    int x;
    for (x =0; x<max; x++)
    {
        if (isdigit(test[x]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (x==max)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        x++;

    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: When you solve your own problems it's better to make an answer and then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Don't write `blah == FALSE`; it's clearer and safer to write `! blah`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the code sample below, you can specify fscanf to read only characters and also a `.` and `' '` (blank space) if you specify the format specifier on what are the acceptable characters to read. If you put a `^` on the front like `[^a-zA-Z. ]`, then it will read everything but those characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[25];
    printf("enter a string: ");
    scanf("%25[a-zA-Z. ]c\n", s); // reads upto 25 chars of a-z/A-Z and '.', ' '.
    printf("s1: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output from the above code:

```
c:\my-src\test-programs>scanf-test.exe
enter a string: dasdasd asdasda 34534536
s1: dasdasd asdasda

c:\my-src\test-programs>scanf-test.exe
enter a string: werfdsfsd3423524525
s1: werfdsfsd
```

See the following links for more details:

[fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

[INFO: scanf() Format Specifications and Syntax](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/67879)

Comment: The buffer must be at least one `char` longer than the field width you give to `scanf`, for the 0-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> but if I use the scanf("%s, c.name) for e.g., it only reads up until
>   to the first space so if I had to add 2 names like Marie Claire, I
>   cannot use scanf.

you can write

```
scanf( "%s %s", c.name, c.surname ); // better with s_scanf
```

> I have a method which checks whether the string contains a digit or
>   not (will provide it) but I was wondering if I could make the fgets()
>   accept only the letters.

No, `fgets` reads characters up to and including `\n` there is nothing you can do about that. Instead use that to your advantage by reading the characters into a buffer and extracting the names e.g. with `sscanf()` or even `strtok()`

again recommending use of _s versions of functions to avoid nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

In short no. But it's nearly always better to separate the input and the checking - so use fgets to read the text, and then check it afterwards with `isalpha` or something similar.

Comment: No problem I found a way :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the `'\n'` from the string.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[SIZE];
int good;

do {
    size_t i;
    char *pend;

    good = 1;
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    pend = strchr(buf, '\n');

    if (pend != NULL)
        *pend = '\0';
    else
         flush_stdin();

    for (i = 0; buf[i] != '\0' && good; i++)
        if (!isdigit(buf[i])
            good = 0;
} while (good != 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it:

```
// ----- Name Input ----- //
        printf ("\nPlease enter Name:\n");
        char nameCheck[50];
        fgets (nameCheck,sizeof (nameCheck),stdin);
        while (cCheck(nameCheck,50) == FALSE)
        {
            fgets(nameCheck,sizeof (nameCheck),stdin);

        }
        strcpy (c.name, nameCheck);
```

I added a new `char nameCheck[50];`

did an `fgets()` on it

did a `while` with the `nameCheck` and then did a `strcpy` :)